# Call function of one module from another module within same crate file in Rust

Tags: rust

```rust
pub mod module_a {
    pub fn function1(a: f32) -> f32 {
        module_b::function2(a)
    }
}
pub mod module_b {
    pub fn function2(a: f32) -> f32 {
        a * 9.0
    }
}
```

I am calling `module_b::function2` from `module_a::function1` but it is showing below error:

```
error[E0433]: failed to resolve: use of undeclared type or module `module_b`
 --> src/lib.rs:3:9
  |
3 |         module_b::function2(a)
  |         ^^^^^^^^ use of undeclared type or module `module_b`
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no `module_b` in `module_a`.
You have to use `crate::module_b::function2` (path from the root of your project) or, equivalently in this case, `super::module_b::function2` (relative path):

```rust
pub mod module_a {
    pub fn function1(a: f32) -> f32 {
        crate::module_b::function2(a)
    }
}
pub mod module_b {
    pub fn function2(a: f32) -> f32 {
        a * 9.0
    }
}
```

Comment: it is giving error on `crate::module_b::function2(a)` my file name is my_modules and it is under Package -> src

Comment: [No it's not](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=8a359832a7d3944f84a32a506b744f52). Are you missing some information in your question?

Comment: My tree for project is:
`package -> src -> **main.rs** and **my_module.rs** `

Comment: It is resolved thanks bro :)
I have used `crate::my_module::moduleB::function2`